# What is it called when a cockroach eats another dead cockroach?

Tags: word-request

I have a question on a cockroach eating another cockroach, because I was in a toilet where I killed a cockroach after few minutes there are another cockroach appear eating the dead cockroach, I am not a cockroach researcher, but my curiosity came out from no where and wanted to know about the word that describe it. We called cannibalism for human, what about cockroach? Roachebalism?

Comment: I'm just glad I didn't encounter this question before dinner.

Comment: Hahahaha yeah hope don't disgust you haha

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it is also called *cannibalism*:

> [Cannibalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism) is the act or practice of humans eating the flesh or internal organs of other human beings. A person who practices cannibalism is called a cannibal. The expression cannibalism has been extended into zoology to mean one individual of a species consuming all or part of another individual of the same species as food, including sexual cannibalism.
>
> ---
>
> In zoology, [cannibalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism_(zoology)) is the act of one individual of a species consuming all or part of another individual of the same species as food.
>   (Wikipedia)

It seems like *animal cannibalism* is in usage, to distinguish it from *human cannibalism*. In particular, you can use the animal name as in *[animal name] cannibalism*:

> 4. CHICKEN
>
> You've heard of the expression "pecking order," right? Well, chickens within a flock have a certain social hierarchy, and they establish that hierarchy with .. pecking. Literally, pecking.
>
> With beaks. Sharp beaks.
>
> This behavior results in drawn blood and torn skin ... and even worse. It can turn into **chicken cannibalism**. And since chickens have a tendency to imitate each other, once one member of the flock goes all Hannibal Lecter on its neighbors, the rest will follow.
>   ([Animal Planet](http://www.animalplanet.com/tv-shows/monster-week/tastes-like-chicken-8-animal-cannibals-that-eat-their-own-kind/))

So *cockroach cannibalism* seems possible too.

Comment: I heard an academic on the radio recently, distinguishing between eating the live of one's own kind and eating the dead of one's own kind. Cannibalism was the former, i.e. killing the victims in order to consume them, rather than eating the already dead. Those who ate the dead in order to stay alive themselves resorted to *necrophagia* not *cannibalism*, by her lights.